# Strict aliasing rule when storing and accessing an array of (pointers to) elements

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

I am analyzing some code that includes (after simplification) the following construct:

```
struct some_array {
    void *elements;
    int nof_elements;
    bool has_pointers;
};
```

The `elements` member can either be an array of `my_type` elements, or an array of pointers to `my_type` elements. Which of the two it is, depends on the value of `has_pointers`.

The `elements` array contents are allocated on the heap, for example like this:

```
    struct some_array arr = {.nof_elements = 10};
    arr.has_pointers = false;
    arr.elements = malloc(arr.nof_elements * sizeof(my_type));
```

or

```
    struct some_array arr = {.nof_elements = 10};
    arr.has_pointers = true;
    arr.elements = malloc(arr.nof_elements * sizeof(my_type *));
    for (size_t i=0; i<arr.nof_elements; i++) {
        ((my_type**)arr.elements)[i] = malloc(sizeof(my_type));
    }
```

The access logic for the `i`th element is like this:

```
my_type *elmt;
if (arr->has_pointers) {
    elmt = ((my_type **)arr->elements)[i];
} else {
    elmt = &((my_type *)arr->elements)[i];
}
```

Assuming that the `has_pointers` member is properly set according to the actual contents of `elements`, this seems work fine. But it is not clear to me whether this construct complies with the strict aliasing rule? Does it comply with this prescription in the C language specification?

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,

I have trouble applying the definition of *effective type* in this case and I can not find a definition of the meaning of *compatible* in this statement.

Comment: I think this is fine. If `has_pointers` is correct, you cast the pointer to the correct type for the object that `elements` points to.

Comment: @Barmar I agree it looks fine, but I do not know what kinds of optimization tricks compilers are allowed to do that may no longer make this fine, possibly because the strict aliasing rule is not followed.

Comment: How is it not followed? You're never accessing any object with a different type than its declaration.

Comment: Strict aliasing is about the actual content of the memory. If you state `elements member can either be an array of my_type elements, or an array of pointers to my_type elements. Which of the two it is, depends on the value of has_pointers` then _if_ that is true, then the code is fine.

Comment: `the definition of effective type in this case` the effective type is what you had stored in the memory. So if you _did_ `my_type *arr[20] = {0}; arr->elements = arr;` then you know effective type. So you have to share where does `arr->elements` point to, to check, if it _accesses_ the proper type. If the statement you are telling is true, _then_ the code "looks" fine. Bottom line, you have to post more code. Compatible type you can check here https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.7p1 , but just it has to be the same type.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks for the link about compatible types, I missed that before. Interesting how strict the definition of "compatible" is. I may ask a different question about that :-)

Comment: I added some code showing how the elements were allocated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing is *not* a strict aliasing violation, and is in fact well defined.

In the first case:

```
struct some_array arr = {.nof_elements = 10};
arr.has_pointers = false;
arr.elements = malloc(arr.nof_elements * sizeof(my_type));
```

`arr.elements` points to space for an array of an array of `my_type`.  Memory obtained via `malloc` is suitably aligned for any purpose, so there's no alignment issue.  Converting the value of `arr.elements` to type `my_type *` correctly allows you to access an array of that time.

Similarly for the second case:

```
struct some_array arr = {.nof_elements = 10};
arr.has_pointers = true;
arr.elements = malloc(arr.nof_elements * sizeof(my_type *));
for (size_t i=0; i<arr.nof_elements; i++) {
    ((my_type**)arr.elements)[i] = malloc(sizeof(my_type));
}
```

`arr.elements` points to space for an array of an array of `my_type *`.  You then cast it to that type `my_type *` to correctly allow access to an array of that type and assign the values.

Then when you later do this:

```
my_type *elmt;
if (arr->has_pointers) {
    elmt = ((my_type **)arr->elements)[i];
} else {
    elmt = &((my_type *)arr->elements)[i];
}
```

The first part is fine because `arr->elements` was treated as an array of `my_type *` and is again used that way, and an element of that array is assigned to `elmt`.  Similarly, the second part is fine because `arr->elements` was treated as an array of `my_type`, and the address of an element of that array is assigned to `elmt`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. For this to be correct, is it essential that the type of the `elements` member is `void *`? For example would your answer still hold if it was defined as `my_type *elements`?

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek Likely yes, but not specified.  Pointers to `my_type *` and `my_type **` are not specified as being interchangeable pedantically, not even the same size.

Comment: Thanks @chux-ReinstateMonica. My bad for posting unclear comments, but when you say "likely yes", are you referring to my first question in the comment ("is it essential...") or my second question ("would the answer still hold...")?

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek The 2nd.   For the first, no not essential to use `void *` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75805161/2410359).

Answer (score 3):

Alterative that addresses the higher level goal:

**Use a `union`**

Casting hints to weak programming.  To avoid:

```
struct some_array {
    union {
      my_type *p;
      my_type **pp;
    } elements;
    int nof_elements;
    bool has_pointers;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am aware of this option and would have considered that if I had the choice, but this is not my code and I am just analyzing it, wondering if it has any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an excellent summary:

[What is the Strict Aliasing Rule and Why do we care?](https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8)

To answer your question:

- [Effective  Type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Effective_type): Every object has an effective type,
- [Compatible types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type#Compatible_types):

> In a C program, the declarations referring to the same object or
> function in different translation units do not have to use the same
> type. They only have to use sufficiently similar types, formally known
> as compatible types. Same applies to function calls and lvalue
> accesses; argument types must be compatible with parameter types and
> lvalue expression type must be compatible with the object type that is
> accessed.
>
> The types T and U are compatible, if
>
> - they are the same type (same name or aliases introduced by a typedef)
> - they are identically cvr-qualified versions of compatible unqualified
>   types they are pointer types and are pointing to compatible types
> - they
>   are array types, and
>
>   - their element types are compatible, and
>   - if both have constant size, that size is the same. Note: arrays of unknown
>     bound are compatible with any array of compatible element type. VLA is
>     compatible with any array of compatible element type. (since C99)
> - they are both structure/union/enumeration types, and
> - (C99)if one is declared with a tag, the other must also be declared with the same
>   tag.
> - if both are completed types, their members must correspond
>   exactly in number, be declared with compatible types, and have
>   matching names.
> - additionally, if they are enumerations, corresponding
>   members must also have the same values.
>   additionally, if they are
>   structures or unions,
>
>   - Corresponding members must be declared in the same order (structures only)
>   - Corresponding bit fields must have the
>     same widths.
> - one is an enumerated type and the other is that
>   enumeration's underlying type
> - they are function types, and
> - their return types are compatible
> - they both use parameter lists, the number
>   of parameters (including the use of the ellipsis) is the same, and the
>   corresponding parameter, after applying array-to-pointer and
>   function-to-pointer type adjustments and after stripping top-level
>   qualifiers, have compatible types
> - one is an old-style (parameter-less)
>   definition, the other has a parameter list, the parameter list does
>   not use an ellipsis and each parameter is compatible (after function
>   parameter type adjustment) with the corresponding old-style parameter
>   after default argument promotions
> - one is an old-style (parameter-less)
>   declaration, the other has a parameter list, the parameter list does
>   not use an ellipsis, and all parameters (after function parameter type
>   adjustment) are unaffected by default argument promotions

- I agree with [dbush's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75805250/421195):

> What you're doing is not a strict aliasing violation, and is in fact well defined.